# Linear regression: Estimator for OLS and Minimum Absolute Deviations

Tags: regression, least-squares, estimators, inference

I've received conflicting information in 2 different statistics classes, and I want to better understand the problem before I ask either of them for clarification

Prof 1: We use OLS for linear regression, but he said its also possible (and that we should, in an ideal world) to use absolute deviations instead as it doesn't inflate the error of poor fitting values as much as OLS does

Prof 2: We can't really use absolute deviations as an alternative to OLS because the estimator in that case is the median rather than the mean, and the majority of the inferential statistics we use are based on means and not medians.

I don't have enough of a background in math/statistics to understand what Prof 2 meant, so I'm looking to clear some things up:

1. What exactly is meant by an estimator in this case? What is that the estimator of? Because in my mind, these methods help you minimize errors for a regression model, which then results in b weights for the regression line, not means or medians
2. Why is the estimator for OLS the mean? How can that be derived simply?
3. Maybe more importantly, why is the estimator for absolute deviations the median? And how do we get that?
4. Is Prof 2 correct in saying that the problem lies in inferential statistics for testing coefficients, like t tests, being mean based?